# Get role in every rule Firebase security

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hello so I have a role in my user collection and I wanted to write the rules depending on the role so if the role is the teacher you can have access to a little more stuff than the parent role. Now my question is there a possibility that I can access the role and use it for every collection, not only the user collection. Like a function that just checks every time what your role is?
I'm doing this for the first time and I'm not pretty sure if I understand everything right, so far.

This is what I have in my rules so far:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
  function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }

   function isOneOfRoles(rsc, array) {
      return isSignedIn() && ((getRole() in array) || rsc.data.openWorld == true);
}
    function getRole() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == 'pädagoge';
}
   
      
    match /posts/{userPosts} {
      allow read: if isSignedIn();
      allow create: if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['pädagoge']);
    }
     match /messages/{messages} {
      allow read, write: if isSignedIn();
      
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "is there a possibility that I can access the role and use it for every collection" => Yes, it is to define functions like you did or like [explained in the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions). I didn't check your rules but what is the problem you are currently encountering with these rules?

Comment: Looking at your rules a little bit more thoroughly it seems that you should probably use `request.resource` instead of `resource` in `if isOneOfRoles(resource, ['pädagoge']);` but this is depending on your exact queries. (Excerpts from the doc: "When writing data, you may want to compare incoming data to existing data. In this case, if your ruleset allows the pending write, the `request.resource` variable contains the future state of the document.")

Comment: I tried to test to create in userPost I'm getting this error:
Function [get] called with incorrect path: /databases/(default)/documents/users/

Comment: How do you test? Via the simulator in the console OR via your app that is deployed?

Comment: Via the Simulator.

Comment: Also, is there any change if you put the `getRole()` function above the `isOneOfRoles()`one? (the second one uses the first one)

Comment: "Via the Simulator" => do you assign a value to Firebase UID in the simulator?

Comment: I don't think I understand why to do this ? And no as you can see in the code

Comment: "I don't think I understand why to do this?" Which part are you taking about? "And no as you can see in the code" Same question :-) Have a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57910883/3371862) for the emulator and user ID.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your security rules in the Firestore "Rules playground". You can see below that you need to do `isOneOfRoles(request.resource, ['pädagoge']);`: with only `resource`, the rule engine cannot check the value of the field `openWorld` beacause the **future state** of the document is contained in the `request.resource` variable, not in the `resource` one. See the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#data_validation) for more details.

You also need to have a corresponding user in the `users` collection with a `role` field with the value `pädagoge`: in my example the user's UID is `A1` (i.e. the ID of the Firestore doc in the `users` collection). See on the second and third screenshots below how we use this value in the `Firebase UID` field in the "Rules playground" simulator.

[image]

[image]
(same screenshot as above, only the left pane was scrolled down to show the `Firebase UID` field)

---

[image]

Comment: I don't get it I did it just how you explain it  and I'm still getting an error this time it's this : Error: simulator.rules line [19], column [37]. Property resource is undefined on object.

Comment: Can you add in your question: 1/ The screenshots of the simulator like I did in the anwser. Don't forget that you need to have an `openWorld` field set to `true` in the new doc => See my first screenshot: under the button "Build Document" you can see the `openWorld` field. 2/ A screenshot of your users collection.

Comment: I updated the post and I have the field set to true

Comment: Can you also show the top of the left pane of the simulator, pls

Comment: Yeah, did it :)

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the top of the simulator configuration on the far left. The part above "password", like my first screenshot.

Comment: Oh sorry haha  I updated the screenshots again

Comment: You need to simulate the doc content by clicking the "Document Erstellen" button and add the `openWorld` field, see my first screenshot.

Comment: You are welcome ;-)BTW sometimes it may be interesting to directly test with a real query, to avoid some of the simulator "complexities"